# Dart, the type int used in the for loop must implement iterable

Tags: flutter, dart, for-loop, iterable

I want to use Dart `for…in loop` in this function but I keep facing this error even though I declared the arr as an `Iterable<int>`

function:

```
void sumOfTwoNumbers(int targetSum, Iterable<int>  arr) {
  for (int i in arr.length-1) {
//stuff
  }
}
```

It's working with a normal for loop though, I don't know how can I fix this, for any help that would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `arr.length` you are trying to iterate over a `int`

`arr` is of type `Iterable` which is expected on the statement:

```
for (var T element in Iterable<T>) { /* ... */ }
```

So:

```dart
void sumOfTwoNumbers(int targetSum, Iterable<int>  arr) {
  for (int i in arr) {
    //stuff
  }
}
```

#### Ignore the last element

And if you want to remove the last element, just create another list from your original list that takes only the first `N - 1` elements, to do that you can use `take` from `Iterable` API:

> Note: in this case if your array is empty the length will be zero which results in 0 - 1 -> -1 which throws a `RangeError` to avoid it you can use `max()` from `dart:math` API

```dart
void sumOfTwoNumbers(int targetSum, Iterable<int>  arr) {
  // Iterable over all elements except by the last one
  for (int i in arr.take(arr.length - 1)) {
    //stuff
  }
}
```

By using `max()`:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void sumOfTwoNumbers(int targetSum, Iterable<int>  arr) {
  // Iterable over all elements except by the last one
  for (int i in arr.take(max(arr.length - 1, 0))) {
    //stuff
  }
}
```

#### Skip the first element

Same rule applies if you want skip the first element, you can use the `skip` API either:

```dart
void sumOfTwoNumbers(int targetSum, Iterable<int>  arr) {
  // Iterable over all elements except by the first one by skipping it
  for (int i in arr.skip(1)) {
    //stuff
  }
}
```

##### Reference

Take a look at [Dart codelabs/iterables](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables) it can help you understand better how collections, lists and iterables works in Dart.

Comment: what if I want to minus 1 from the list? like  `for (int i in arr-1)` it keep giving an error

Comment: @YassineBENNKHAY I updated my answer hope it can answer your question